# Trouble accessing firebase query results in document template

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

new to vue and firebase but stuck on this for hours.  I have a vue3 app running a specific firebase9 query that will only return a maximum of 1 row (i.e. includes limit 1).  The results are being returned but I am having trouble accessing the data so I can pass up to the template. I am using an example from a tutorial that was designed to return multiple rows from FB then iterate through in the template using v-for but in this case it will only ever be one row.  All the tutorials I can find are similar not addressing how to deal with one row (or document) being returned.  Oddly, the data is being returned to _rawValue but I can't seem to get to it...

Here's the JS snippet:

```
let collectionRef = collection(db, c)
collectionRef = query(collectionRef, where(...q), orderBy(...ob), limit(...lmt))

const unsub = onSnapshot(collectionRef, snapshot => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
    })
    // update values
    documents.value = results        
})

return { documents }
```

Here's the Vue snippet:

```
const { documents: lastEvent } = getCollectionRt(
  'events',
  ['userId', '==', user.value.uid],
  ['created', 'desc'],
  ['1']
  )
console.log('lastevent: ', lastEvent)
```

I can see that lastEvent does indeed contain an array with the values I am looking for so the query is running and returning, BUT, it is listed in something called "_rawValue" that I can't seem to access.  For example I would like to set a variable to one of the values being returned like let myVar = lastEvent.id or lastEvent.created, etc.

[edit: use case is that I want to query the users last input so I that can set some of the form data default values based on their last entry]

Any help or reference to get me unstuck would be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuP52.png)

Comment: Maybe my question could be simplified to something like, "how can I access the data stored in 'lastEvent'?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution.  Probably hacky but works.

First modify the getCollectionRt.js that runs the query as

```
...
const document = ref(null)
collectionRef = query(collectionRef, where(...q), orderBy(...ob), limit(...lmt)) 

const unsub = onSnapshot(collectionRef, snapshot => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        document.value = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
    })
    // update values
    documents.value = results        
})
return { documents, document }
```

then pull in 'document' and return in vue as:

```
const { documents: lastEvent, document } = getCollectionRt(
  'events',
  ['userId', '==', user.value.uid],
  ['created', 'desc'],
  ['1']
  )
...
return {..., document }
```

then I can access it in the template as {{ document.id}}

Although this works, definitely spend more time learning about workign with object/arrays in VueJS